# Optimal MYSQL query for longest prefix matching in a table with 5 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table with 5 million of rows

```
CREATE TABLE dummy_table (
            num VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            rsid VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
            list VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (num, rsid)
            );
```

**`num` field in the table is the prefix of some dynamic number('123457467890' in above query).** Now I need to fetch `list` column based on `num` and `rsid` and in this `num` must be the longest prefix match of incoming number. For getting `list` I've a below query:

```
select list 
from dummy_table 
where '123457467890' like CONCAT(num, '%') 
  and rsid = '123' 
order by LENGTH(num) desc LIMIT 1;
```

**NOTE: 123457467890`: this number will be different each time we throw a query**

Now the problem is for executing this query, MYSQL is taking about 0.80 seconds which is very high in my case. I need to throw more than 1000 query in a second. Is there any way to optimize this query to this extent. Can anyone help to achieve this result?

Comment: It might be just the general stupor that tends to descend at this time of year, but I can't quite see what you're after. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first optimisation would be:
- Add another column "length"
- Add an index on `(rsid, length DESC, num)`

Now your query is only very slightly different:
- `SELECT list FROM dummy_table WHERE '123457467890' LIKE CONCAT(num, '%') AND rsid = '123' ORDER BY length DESC LIMIT 1;`

But, by including the length in the index, the query *should* be able to stop at the first hit.

***However...***

This is always going to be a costly process.  The worst case scenario being that you find no matches - and so have to scan the full set of (rsid = '123') records no matter what.

The optimisation above isn't going to help optimise the worst case scenarios, only the best case scenarios.  *(It will help more the longer the match is, but won't help as much for shorter matches.)*

What you MAY be forced to do is something like...
1. Create a temporary table
2. Insert '1234567890' in to it
3. Insert '123456789' in to it
4. Insert '12345678' in to it
.
.
.
n. Insert '1' in to it

At this point you have every possible match for your search string in your temporary table.

Then your query can instead potentially use an index seek.  Potentially finding 10 matches (in this case) and then finding the longest of those.

```
-- Index now needs to be (rsid, num, length)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  dummy_table
INNER JOIN
  your_search_table
    ON dummy_table.num = your_search_table.num
WHERE
  rsid = '123'
ORDER BY
  dummy_table.length
LIMIT
  1
```

Comment: I agree on your first approach of adding another column length. But in your second suggestion, as I already mentioned that this number '123457467890' will be a dynamic number i.e it might be different for each query so creating the temporary table will not be feasible. Do you have any another suggestion considering this fact?

Comment: There is no reason not to create the temporary table.  Create it, write a loop to populate it with all the possible shorter values, execute the query, all in one session.  As its temporary there is no concurrency problem.

Answer (score 1):

The test `'123457467890' like CONCAT(num, '%')` cannot be optimized with an index. However, it's equivalent to:

```
num IN ('1', '12', '123', '1234', '12345', '123456', '1234567', '12345678', '123456789', '1234567890')
```

which *can* be optimized if you have an index on the `num` column.

If you're generating the query from a programming language, it should be relatively simple to convert it to this format. For instance, in PHP it would be:

```
$nums = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= strlen($number); $i++) {
    $nums[] = "'" . substr($number, 0, $i) . "'";
}
$where = 'num IN (' . implode(', ', $nums) . ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that fixed length match queries will run very fast with the proper indexes.

```
-- 10 number match
select list from dummy_table 
where '123457467890' = num and rsid = '123';

-- 9 number match
select list 
from dummy_table 
where '12345746789' = num and rsid = '123';
```

Wrap in code to start with the length of the incoming string and stop when a match is found. Even for a full 16 length string there will be a max of 16 queries. While it does do multiple queries it avoids evaluating any database fields, doing any comparisons shorter than the longest match or creating an intermediate result set.

Now to do 1000 queries a second it depends if they are independent or can be run as a batch by loading an extra table with what strings you want results for and running sixteen UPDATE statements based on the above queries to fill it with the results.